# What is the modern approach for mobile specific templates?

Tags: django, mobile, subdomain

I'm using Django 2.1 with python 3.5 and I'm looking to modify existing or provide mobile specific templates, mainly for rendering differences.

Is it still a thing to support a mobile subdomain (m.mysite)?

I've looked into a few solutions such as: Django-mobile and Django-subdomain but these packages seem to be out of date. There is also user_agents and amp_tools.

What is the standard approach for this application these days?

Thanks for your help.